# Trim title on an only single page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to  trim title on an only single page (page-id: 3988)

I’m trying this code. But it’s not working.

Can anybody please help me with this.

Regards,

```
function limit_word_count($title) {
    $len = 5; //change this to the number of words
    if (is_page(3988)) {
        if (str_word_count($title) > $len) {
            $keys = array_keys(str_word_count($title, 2));
            $title = substr($title, 0, $keys[$len]);
        }
    return $title;
    }
}

add_filter(‘the_title’, ‘limit_word_count’);
```

In result, this code removes the title from the page

Comment: But where do you use `trim()` exactly?

Comment: `add_filter(‘the_title’, ‘limit_word_count’);` can only causes errors, you need to use the correct quote characters (`'` or `"`), not “curly” ones.

Comment: I think this code is using some other method (substr )to trim title as I copied code from the website.
Is there any other code which can help?

Comment: The code to reduce the number of words in your title works fine from what I can see. The error must be somewhere else. Try @misorude's suggestion. And otherwise do some debugged with to see where the title gets lost.

Comment: @misorude quote is not creating issues.

Comment: Code to trim title is working fine. The only problem is this is not working with if (is_page) condition as I want to trim title on only one page with id 3988.

Comment: Can you add the code for your `is_page` function? If the issue is there then that would help a lot.

Comment: _“quote is not creating issues”_ - they should. Fix them. _“as I copied code from the website”_ - many websites make the mistake of replacing the proper quotes with curly ones, when _displaying_ code. Doesn’t change the fact that this is not correct, so – fix it.

Comment: @DirkScholten that’s WP default functionality, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ (I also added the `wordpress` tag to the question now, for a little more clarity.)

Comment: Ah didn't realise it was wordpress. @WaseemAslam Maybe you can use `get_post` to retrieve some info on the page. See what ID it thinks it is. There has to be a reason why it always returns true.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I'm using the function in the function.php file and I want if condition to execute there and show only 5 words from the title. Can you help me update the code described in the question?

Comment: Move the `return $title` out of the if statement.

Comment: tried but not working. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1 -- you can use [mb_strimwidth](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) function for example :

```
echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 50, '...');
```

2 -- and if you don't want use php simply with css can do this.with this code you can Limit titles to one line only. just replace title class.

```
.single .titleclass {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

3 -- also you can use [wp_trim_words()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/) function for wordpress.

```
wp_trim_words( string $text, int $num_words = 55, string $more = null )
```

for example :

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 15 ); ?>
```

4-- use this function :

```
function limit_word_count($title) {

        // limit to 5 words
        return wp_trim_words( $title, 5, '' );

    }

add_filter('the_title', 'limit_word_count');
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I'm using the function in the function.php file and I want if condition to execute there and show only 5 words from the title. Can you help me update the code described in the question?

Comment: function added :)